# How to define types of columns while loading dataframe in polars?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm using [polars](https://docs.rs/polars/0.12.1/polars/) and I would like to define the type of the columns while loading a dataframe. In pandas, I can use `dtype`:

```py
df=pd.read_csv("iris.csv", dtype={'petal_length':str})
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in polars, but without success until now. Here is what I have tried:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::collections::HashMap;


fn main() {
    let df = example();
    println!("{:?}", df.expect("Cannot find dataframe").head(Some(10)))
}

fn example() -> Result<DataFrame> {
    let file = File::open("iris.csv")
                    .expect("could not read file");
    let mut myschema = HashMap::new();
    myschema.insert("sepal_length", f64);
    myschema.insert("sepal_width", f64); 
    myschema.insert("petal_length",String); 
    myschema.insert("petal_width", f64); 
    myschema.insert("species", String); 

    CsvReader::new(file)
            .with_schema(myschema)
            .has_header(true)
            .finish()
}
```

My doubt is what type of data the implementation `with_schema` expects? I printed the schema of the DataFrame loaded using `infer_schema(None)`.This prints a object that looks like a dictionary:

```
Schema { fields: [Field { name: "sepal_length", data_type: Float64 }, Field { name: "sepal_width", data_type: Float64 }, Field { name: "petal_length", data_type: Float64 }, Field { name: "petal_width", data_type: Float64 }, Field { name: "species", data_type: Utf8 }] }
```

But I cannot figure what object I should use to implement my schema.

Also, there is a way to specify the type of one variable, instead of all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with_schema` method expects an `Arc<Schema>` type, not a `Hashmap`.

The following code works:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn example() -> Result<DataFrame> {
    let file = "iris.csv";

    let myschema = Schema::new(
        vec![
            Field::new("sepal_length", DataType::Float64),
            Field::new("sepal_width", DataType::Float64),
            Field::new("petal_length", DataType::Utf8),
            Field::new("petal_width", DataType::Float64),
            Field::new("species", DataType::Utf8),
        ]
    );

    CsvReader::from_path(file)?
        .with_schema(Arc::new(myschema))
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()
}
```

> Also, there is a way to specify the type of one variable, instead of all of them?

Yes, you can use `with_dtype_overwrite`. Which expects a partial schema.

Comment: Today, this code does not compile anymore.

When I try to use it, I get the message: 

`argument of type Vec<polars::prelude::Field> unexpected`

Any idea?

Comment: you might have to make the VECTOR into an iterator using `.into_iter()`

Answer (score 1):

A slight update to ritche46's answer. As Robert stated, the vector needs to be changed to an iterator. And it looks like we should use `from` now instead of `new`? I've not executed the code below, but it compiles.

```
...
        let myschema = Schema::from(
            vec![
                Field::new("sepal_length", DataType::Float64),
                Field::new("sepal_width", DataType::Float64),
                Field::new("petal_length", DataType::Utf8),
                Field::new("petal_width", DataType::Float64),
                Field::new("species", DataType::Utf8),
            ]
            .into_iter(),
        );
...
```